# Dropwizard configuration not working with a Shaded jar

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard, dropwizard-templates

I am facing the following issue when trying to run a shaded jar with properties in the configuration.yaml file. (not occurred when directly ran the main class)

run command: `java -jar target/mlsdata-1.0.jar server configuration.yaml`

ERROR:

```html
io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: configuration.yaml has an error:
  * Failed to parse configuration at: server.applicationConnectors.[0]; Could not resolve type id 'http' as a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.jetty.ConnectorFactory]: known type ids = [] (for POJO property 'applicationConnectors')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.zaplabs.MlsConfiguration["server"]->io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory["applicationConnectors"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

From what I understood from various sources, it could be a maven packaging issue. Solutions didn't help me though.

Here is my build setup in POM.

`

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.zaplabs.MlsApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                                <mainClass>com.zaplabs.MlsApplication</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"/>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.zaplabs.MlsApplication</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

Dropwizard version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Configuration.yaml

```html
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9000
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9001

# Database settings.
database:
    # the name of the JDBC driver, mysql in our case
    driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    # the username
    user: xxx
    # the password
    password: xxx
    # the JDBC URL
    url: jdbc:mysql://xxx
    properties:
      charSet: UTF-8
      maxWaitForConnection: 1s
      validationQuery: "/* MyService Health Check */ SELECT 1"
      minSize: 8
      maxSize: 32
      checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
      evictionInterval: 10s
      minIdleTime: 1 minute
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
      hibernate.show_sql: true
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate # validates schema when service is started
```

Answer (score 2):

So i had the same issue and i found the solution [here](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/docs/getting-started.html)

Also i had to use the following plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
<configuration>
    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
    <filters>
        <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </filter>
    </filters>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <mainClass>com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldApplication</mainClass>
                </transformer>
            </transformers>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is because of dependency issues between hibernate and dropwizard-core, after  adding <dependency management> it worked.